# Polynomial Tricky Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

Here is a problem that is a bit hard for me. I can understand the question but can't make out how to approach. Please post a complete solution to the given question. I started with solving $P(P(1)) = P(P(2)) = 0$. But it didn't helped

$P(x) = x^2 + ax + b$

$P(P(1)) = P(P(2)) = 0$

$P(1) \ne P(2)$

Fro the given conditions, find the value of $\textbf{-2P(0)}$.

Comment: If you worked out $P(P(1))$ and $P(P(2))$ tell us what you got.

Comment: You should show us your idea to solve the problem. I suppose you started writing $P(P(1))$ and $P(P(2))$...

Comment: Why are you thinking so. I am in great stress

Comment: Suryansh, I am ready to share an answer once you share your ideas on how to approach the problem.

Comment: It may be easy but I am not getting it

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Haran I have already edited the question and told about my progress

Comment: What did you get as their values?

Answer (score 2):

We can observe from substitution that $P(1)=a+b+1$ and $P(2)=2a+b+4$. These are the roots of the polynomial $P$. By Vieta's formulae, we then have $a=-(P(1)+P(2))=-(3a+2b+5)$, and we also have $b=P(1)P(2)=(a+b+1)(2a+b+4)$.

From the first equation, we get $a=\frac{-(2b+5)}{4}$. When substituting this in the second equation:
$$8b=(-2b-5+4b+4)(-2b-5+2b+8)=3(2b-1)$$
$$8b=6b-3 \implies b=-\frac{3}{2}$$

Hence, we have:
$$-2P(0) = -2b = -2 \bigg(\frac{-3}{2} \bigg)=3$$

Comment: -2 ( -3/2) = 3. Not 6

Comment: It's not correct @Haran

Comment: Made the edit, my bad

Answer (score 2):

$P(1)$ and $P(2)$ are two distinct roots of $P$, and we know that $P$ has only two roots (at most). So we have these two roots : $P(1)=1+a+b$ and $P(2)=4+2a+b$.

So $$P(X) = (X-P(1))(X-P(2)) = (X-1-a-b)(X-4-2a-b)$$

So $-2P(0) = -2P(1)P(2)$.

But we know more about the roots in fact we know they are $\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}$ and $\frac{-a-\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}$. So the product of both is $b$.

So $-2P(0) = -2b$.

Let's determine $b$.

First the sum of the two roots is $-a$ and also $5+3a+2b$. So $4a+2b+5=0$. And with the difference of the two roots we get (by taking the square) $a^2-4b=(3+a)^2$ so $6a+4b+9=0$.

By multiplying the first equation by $2$, the second by $3$, and taking the difference, we get $$2b=-3$$

So $$-2P(0) = 6$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$P(2)-P(1)=3+a$$

$$P(P(2))-P(P(1))=(3+a)(5+4a+2b)$$

Comment: How do you get the second equation ?

Comment: With the power of *Mathematica*.

Comment: And how do you get to the solution from this ?

Comment: $5+4a+2b=0$ and solve $P(P(1))=0$

Comment: That's the same idea as you.

Comment: Mh, that might be added in the hint. What about $3+a=0$ ?

Comment: rejecting coz it is non-zero.

Comment: How do you know ?

Comment: $P(P(1)) \, \ne \, P(P(2))$ which is  given by the question.

Comment: You probably mean $P(1)\ne P(2)$.

Comment: Yep typo.  $$y_j= x_j^2+ax_j+b$$
$$f(y_2)-f(y_1)=(y_2-y_1)(x_1+y_2+a)$$